# If $f(x)=x$ for $0 \leq x \leq e$ and $f(x)=xf(\ln(x))$ for $x>e$, then does the series $\sum\limits_n\frac1{f(n)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals

> Let $f(x)=x$ if $0 \leq x \leq e$, $f(x)=xf(\ln(x))$ if $x>e$. 
>   Does the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq1}{\frac{1}{f(n)}}$ converge?

My attempt :

One can note that for all  $n\geq 3$, there exist $k\geq 1$ such that $$f(n)=n\ln(n)\ln(\ln(n))\cdots\ln^{(k)}(n)$$ where  $\ln^{(k)}$ refers to the function $\ln$ composed by itself $k$ times.

Then, consider
$$
I_k=\int_{\exp^{(k)}(1)}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t\ln(t)\dots\ln^{(k)}(t)}dt.
$$
By substituting  $t=e^u$, we have
$$
I_k=\int_{exp^{(k-1)}(1)}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{e^uu\ln(u)\dots\ln^{(k-1)}(u)}e^udu=I_{k-1},
$$

Since $I_1=\int_e^{+\infty}\frac{1}{t\ln(t)}dt$ diverges then $I_k$ diverges too.

Then, I would like to do an integral test, unfortunately $k$ is $n$-dependent.

So, I think the trick is to choose a good interval.

Any ideas for this ?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111244/series-with-iterated-logs-does-it-converge

Comment: Putnam question

Comment: This is the [2008 Putnam A4](http://www.math.harvard.edu/putnam/2008/2008.pdf) question. Various solutions exist on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f$ is increasing hence
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{f(n)}\geqslant\sum_{n\geqslant1}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm dx}{f(x)}=\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{f(x)}.
$$
Define a sequence $(x_n)$ by $x_0=1$ and, for every $n\geqslant0$, $x_{n+1}=\mathrm e^{x_n}$, and, for every $n\geqslant0$, let
$$
J_n=\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}\frac{\mathrm dx}{f(x)}.
$$ 
Then, for every $n\geqslant1$, the change of variable $t=\ln x$ sends the interval $(x_n,x_{n+1})$ to the interval $(x_{n-1},x_n)$ hence
$$
J_n=\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}\frac{\mathrm dx}{xf(\ln x)}=\int_{x_{n-1}}^{x_{n}}\frac{\mathrm dt}{f(t)}=J_{n-1}.
$$
Thus, for every $n\geqslant0$,
$$
J_n=J_0=\int_1^\mathrm e\frac{\mathrm dx}x=1,
$$
in particular,
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{f(x)}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}J_n
$$
diverges, hence the series $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{f(n)}$ diverges.

Comment: Oh, what I did was too 'heavy', thank you @Did!

Answer (score 1):

This is the 2008 Putnam A4 question.

This solution is presented by Kiran Kedlaya and Lenny Ng

[image]